# grouping in pandas data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I have a pandas data frame as below. I want to get the list of 'Job_No' for all the combinations of ('User_ID', 'Exec_No')

```
   User_ID Exec_No Job_No
1:    2      1      1   
2:    2      2      2 
3:    3      2      3
4:    1      2      4
5:    1      1      5
6:    3      2      6
7:    2      2      7
8:    1      1      8
```

The desired output is another data frame that looks like

```
  User_ID Exec_No Job_No
1:    2      1      [1]   
2:    2      2      [2,7] 
3:    3      2      [3,6]
4:    1      2      [4]
5:    1      1      [5,8]
```

How do I do this using a few lines of code?

Also, the data frame is expected to have around a million rows. Therefore the performance is also important.

Answer (score 2):

As a note, if you care about performance, storing lists in a DataFrame is not very efficient. After grouping the data, Job_No values can be accessed immediately, no need to create a new DataFrame (memory !) holding lists of Job_No per (User_Id, Exec_No) pair.

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   User_ID  Exec_No  Job_No
0        2        1       1
1        2        2       2
2        3        2       3
3        1        2       4
4        1        1       5
5        3        2       6
6        2        2       7
7        1        1       8

In [22]: grouped = df.groupby(['User_ID', 'Exec_No'])

In [23]: grouped.get_group((3, 2))
Out[23]:
   User_ID  Exec_No  Job_No
2        3        2       3
5        3        2       6

In [24]: grouped.get_group((3, 2))['Job_No']
Out[24]:
2    3
5    6
Name: Job_No, dtype: int64

In [25]: list(grouped.get_group((3, 2))['Job_No'])
Out[25]: [3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is straight forward.

say if 'df' is the dataframe object, then

```
grp_df = df.groupby(['User_ID','Exec_No'])
newdf  = grp_df['Job_No']
```

Comment: The `grp_df` is a 'GroupBy object', not a DataFrame. Selecting a column from it returns a Groupby object again, so you would still need to do something like `grp_df['Job_No'].apply(lambda x: x.values)`.

Answer (score 0):

This will give a Series in return:

```
df.groupby(['User_ID', 'Exec_No']).apply(lambda x: x.Job_No.values)
```

Wrapping it in a Series in the apply returns a DataFrame:

```
df.groupby(['User_ID', 'Exec_No']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x.Job_No.values]))

User_ID Exec_No        
1       1        [5, 8]
        2           [4]
2       1           [1]
        2        [2, 7]
3       2        [3, 6]
```

It would be nice if the `name=` of the Series would be used as the resulting column name, but it isnt.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User_ID' : [2,2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1], 'Exec_No': [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1], 'Job_No':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}, columns=['User_ID', 'Exec_No','Job_No'])

df
User_ID Exec_No Job_No
0    2   1   1
1    2   2   2
2    3   2   3
3    1   2   4
4    1   1   5
5    3   2   6
6    2   2   7
7    1   1   8
```

Let's do the group by:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['User_ID', 'Exec_No'], sort=False).apply(lambda x: list(x['Job_No']))
df2    
User_ID  Exec_No
2        1             [1]
         2          [2, 7]
3        2          [3, 6]
1        1          [5, 8]
         2             [4]
```

and put the way you wanted it:

```
df2.reset_index()

User_ID Exec_No 0
0    2   1   [1]
1    2   2   [2, 7]
2    3   2   [3, 6]
3    1   1   [5, 8]
4    1   2   [4]
```